# Is it possible to make a custom path with gps coordinates and have google maps traverse the path by pointing to next gps coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I would like to take the gps coordinates of a certain custom path (for the purposes of this, lets say its a path across my lawn and its in a circle or zigzag) and would like to have google maps point to each point in the path toward the end point. Would it be possible to get to the last point on the path without pointing to the last point first? It would traverse the circle and end at the last point.

Comment: *"is it possible?"* ... certainly. Is anyone going to write up a bunch of code for this? Not likely...this isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service or a free code writing service

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't ask for code, as you can read above. I'm not sure why you felt compelled to assume I wanted you to write code for me. Users like you are the reason this site gets a bad rep at times. I come here to ask questions from people that I know have more knowledge in these area and was looking for some guidance . But thanks for the "answer" I was actually looking for more along the lines of API calls to look into. Can you please point me to the section where I asked if you could write this code for me?

Comment: OK... but look at it from our perspective.... all you really asked was *"is it possible?"* which is really a boolean yes/no situation. Being pragmatic...what would you honestly expect as an answer?

Comment: If anything, a yes or no would suffice, the condescending nature of your comment was obviously unnecessary.

Comment: Just like any problem...break this down into smaller components and start researching the basics in small chunks. Then start connecting them. When you have real code and a specific problem you will get lots of help here...that's how the site works

Comment: Fine...read it as you feel...but not reading how this site works in the tour that was shown to you when you got signed up is not our fault either. Spend a few minutes reading sections of [help]

Comment: acting like a dick when someone asks a question isn't how this site works either.

Comment: Not sure how you can read intent into a brief comment when all that was stated was fact. A significant part of a programmers life is research..get used to it